# JavaScript counter up on HTML span tag element using jquery.counterup.min.js doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I am currently developing a Django app, and I am trying to set up a counter to display a given integer on the main page.

Here is the JavaScript stuff I load on my HTML template (that is not the entire file):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'EpiDB/jquery-3.2.0.min.js' %}">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'EpiDB/jquery.tablesorter.min.js' %}">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() 
        { 
        $("#annotable").tablesorter(); 
        } 
    );
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'EpiDB/jquery.searchable-1.0.0.min.js' %}">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $( '#annotable' ).searchable({
        searchField: '#annotsearch',
        striped: true,
            oddRow: { 'background-color': '#e2e9f3' },
            evenRow: { 'background-color': '#ffffff' },
        searchType: 'fuzzy'
        })
    });
</script>
    <!-- popper js -->
    <script src="{% static 'EpiDB/popper.min.js' %}"></script>
    <!-- bootstrap js -->
    <script src="{% static 'EpiDB/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
    <!-- easing js -->
    <script src="{% static 'EpiDB/jquery.magnific-popup.js' %}"></script>
    <!-- swiper js -->
    <script src="{% static 'EpiDB/swiper.min.js' %}"></script>
    <!-- swiper js -->
    <script src="{% static 'EpiDB/masonry.pkgd.js' %}"></script>
    <!-- particles js -->
    <script src="{% static 'EpiDB/owl.carousel.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'EpiDB/jquery.nice-select.min.js' %}"></script>
    <!-- swiper js -->
    <script src="{% static 'EpiDB/slick.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'EpiDB/waypoints.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'EpiDB/jquery.counterup.min.js' %}"></script>
```

All content of my page using the other JavaScript files is working fine except the **counter up**. So I read bit about the way **jquery.counterup.min.js** was supposed to work, and I came to the conclusion that either I am doing something wrong with the **waypoints.min.js** (jQuery Waypoints - v2.0.3) file or the **jquery-3.2.0.min.js**.

I have found that [a GitHub issue](https://github.com/bfintal/Counter-Up/issues/60) was still open mentioning possible incompatibilities with jQuery 3.1 (and so with jQuery 3.2 I suppose).

By the way this is the piece of HTML I try to make work, unsuccessfully so far:

```
<span class="counter">1200</span>
```

So my question is why is the counter up not working, what is the source of the problem (knowing that everything else works perfectly), and if the problem is coming from the version of my **jquery-3.2.0.min.js** is there any fix, or any option to avoid using an older version of jQuery? if you have a solution using a newer version of jQuery however, I am interested.

It is both not working in Firefox (V 70.0.1) and Chromium (V 78.0.3904.108).

Comment: Did you try last comment from issue you shared? https://github.com/bfintal/Counter-Up/issues/60#issuecomment-504527327

Comment: Where is the script which initialize "counterUp" plugin? I mean: $('.counter').counterUp();

Comment: @Manjunath Thank you for asking: yes I also tried that and it does not change anything unfortunately. By the way by saying that it doesn't work, I mean that : despite there is no error message displayed, either on the page or in the terminal, the value of the span tag is displayed correctly on the page, but the counter up is just not working.

Comment: @Sercanözen as stupid as I might sound: I read that I had to initialize it, but I have absolutely no idea where I should write the code, and what I should write.

I tried to include some javascript in the html but it didn't work.

If you have a working solution in the form of: <script type="text/javascript"> your solution for initialization </script>
Please post it in the comment and I will let you know if it works ;) .
Thanks for your help !

Comment: @Sercanözen I just tried `<script type="text/javascript">
 $('.counter').counterUp();
</script>` and it does not change anything.

Comment: @YoannPageaud please write like this: $(document).ready(function()   { $('.counter').counterUp();} );

Comment: Thank you very much @Sercanözen & Manjunath both of your answer were really usefull.
Sercanözen I was indeed missing the initialization, your last comment worked perfectly with the "jquery.waypoints.js" file from the github issue mentioned above.
Sercanözen I think you won the right to provide the answer now :) ! Congratulations !

Comment: @Manjunath the "jquery.waypoints.js" file provided in the github issue was indeed useful ! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the solution was to use the "jquery.waypoints.js" file mentioned in [this Github issue](http://github.com/bfintal/Counter-Up/issues/60#issuecomment-504527327).

And then add to the html template the activation of CounterUp.

This was the important part:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'EpiDB/jquery-3.2.0.min.js' %}">
</script>
<script src="{% static 'EpiDB/jquery.waypoints.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'EpiDB/jquery.counterup.min.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() { $('.counter').counterUp();} );
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for wanting to give upvotes to others here! However, there is nothing on the page from those helpers to upvote (comments can be marked as useful, but it does not have much of an effect on someone's account). If you would like to upvote someone, encourage them to make a full and useful answer, and then you can upvote them. We would rather not encourage readers to go hunting for unrelated answers made by those folks, as there is a risk that material would be upvoted that does not really merit it (even if the assistance here was helpful).

Comment: In other words, voting should be as organic as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, the library is not needed. it's able with a little function.

```
var counter =  function (index, max ,result) {
     index++;
     result(index);
     if (index < max)
          setTimeout(this.counter, 70, index, max ,result);
     }
counter(0 ,10 , (value)=>{document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML = value;});
```